# Angular 2 - Variable in view not updatet

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to show/hide a header in my Angular2 app, depending on the login state of the user. The header only should be visible, if the user is logged in. For the login i am using parse (parse.com). Everything is working fine but the variable, which indicates if the header should be visible or not, is not updating in the view. In the component class i can see, that the variable is set to true after login but the template does not update.
The flow is:
- User goes to login page and no header should be there
- User logges in
- User will be redirected to the dashboard and the header should be visible

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ParseProviderService } from "../../shared/providers/parse-provider.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector : 'app-header',
    templateUrl : './header.component.html',
    styleUrls : [ './header.component.css' ]
})
export class HeaderComponent {

    public showHeader: boolean;

    constructor(private parseProviderService: ParseProviderService,
                private router: Router) {
        this.showHeader = !!this.parseProviderService.current();
        console.log("Header: ", this.showHeader); // Shows the login state
        this.parseProviderService.getCurrentSubject().subscribe((show) => {
            console.log(show); // show == true after login
            this.showHeader = show; // Also if show == true the template will not update
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this.parseProviderService.logout().then(() => {
            this.parseProviderService.getCurrentSubject().next(false);
            this.router.navigate(['/user/login']);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

}
```

In my template i have something like this:

```
Show Header: {{ showHeader }}
```

I could not find it out since several days :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to invoke change detection manually, for example by using `detectChanges()`:

```ts
constructor(private parseProviderService: ParseProviderService,
            private router: Router, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.showHeader = !!this.parseProviderService.current();
    console.log("Header: ", this.showHeader); // Shows the login state
    this.parseProviderService.getCurrentSubject().subscribe((show) => {
        console.log(show); // show == true after login
        this.showHeader = show; // Also if show == true the template will not update
        cdRef.detectChanges(); // <<<<< added
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Günter! Works like a charm. Do you know, why i need to implement it by myself?

Comment: Looks like `parseProviderService` somehow leaves Angulars zone. Angular recognizes async callbacks and runs change detection afterwards. Somehow parse seems not to be fully compatible with zone.js.